Update on duplicate with condition to check only ONCE to reduce I/O operations
I'm using Mysql query like this:
INSERT INTO test 
    (id, name, customerId, timestamp, status, lastTimestamp, testId, testCapacity)
    values(1, 'test1', 2, 1717415401000, 'SAFE', 1717415401000, 'test123', 50)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    lastTimestamp = CASE WHEN timestamp < VALUES(timestamp) THEN VALUES(timestamp) ELSE lastTimestamp END,
    status = CASE WHEN timestamp < VALUES(timestamp) THEN VALUES(status) ELSE status END,
    testCapacity = CASE WHEN timestamp < VALUES(timestamp) THEN VALUES(testCapacity) ELSE testCapacity END,
    timestamp = CASE WHEN timestamp < VALUES(timestamp) THEN VALUES(timestamp) ELSE timestamp END


The above query is working fine. But Since, I'm using same condition for multiple updates it take 'n' number of I/O operations to update the record. And with increase in update queries, this multiple I/O operation is utilising MYSQL resources.
I want to have query something like this:
INSERT INTO test 
    (id, name, customerId, timestamp, status, lastTimestamp, testId, testCapacity)
    values(1, 'test1', 2, 1717415401000, 'SAFE', 1717415401000, 'test123', 50)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    // condition to check timestamp ONCE and direct update all the fields
    if(timestamp < VALUE(timestamp))
    {
     lastTimestamp = lastTimestamp,
     status = status,
     testCapacity = testCapacity,
     timestamp = timestamp
    }


Thanks for your time :)

Please clarify by adding table definition, sample data and expected outcome as text btw testing timestamp multiple times won't affect i/o..

lastTimestamp = CASE WHEN timestamp < VALUES(timestamp) THEN VALUES(timestamp) ELSE lastTimestamp END There exists LEAST() and GREATEST() functions...

I don't think this is possible, as update clause need to know one by one the names that need updating

Yes @Akina, even with GREATEST() the I/O operation would not decrease.

@Shadow Any other approach that you can suggest? One option I am thinking of is Stored procedure with combination of select, insert and delete(select if the record is present on condition, if yes then delete it and insert the newer one). But not sure how efficiency it will provide.

@P.Salmon The table has compound Unique key on ('customerId', 'name', 'status') and the fields are of type int, bigint, and varchar

I don't understand what i/o operations your are speaking about. When duplicate violation is detected then the server must unconditionally load the whole datafile page(s) where this duplicated row is posessed (if it not present in the table cache already, of course). Then all expressions from SET clause are processed over this row - this step does not need in any i/o. And, finally, server checks does these pages were altered and, if so, they are written to the disk, again unconditionally and completely... What i/o operations do you want to reduce?
